# Uncaught Throw generated by JLink or UseFrontEnd

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

This example routine generates two Throw::nocatch warning messages in the kernel window.  Can they be handled somehow?

The example consists of this code in a file "test.m" created in C:\Temp:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
$FrontEndLaunchCommand = "Mathematica.exe";
UseFrontEnd[NotebookWrite[CreateDocument[], "Testing"]];
```

Then these commands pasted and run at the Windows Command Prompt:

```
PATH = C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\;%PATH%
start MathKernel -noprompt -initfile "C:\Temp\test.m"
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The reason for using UseFrontEnd as opposed to UsingFrontEnd is that an interactive front end may be required to preserve output and messages from notebooks that are usually run interactively.  For example, with C:\Temp\test.m modified like so:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
$FrontEndLaunchCommand="Mathematica.exe";
UseFrontEnd[
nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\Temp\\run.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
SelectionEvaluate[nb];
];
Pause[10];
CloseFrontEnd[];
```

and a notebook C:\Temp\run.nb created with a single cell containing:

```
x1 = 0; While[x1 < 1000000,
 If[Mod[x1, 100000] == 0,
  Print["x1=" <> ToString[x1]]]; x1++];
NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]];
NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]];
```

this code, launched from a Windows Command Prompt, will run interactively and save its output.  This is not possible to achieve using UsingFrontEnd or MathKernel -script "C:\Temp\test.m".

Comment: @ Leonid, It works fine from the kernel window here too. The problem seems to be some interaction between the -initfile method and JLink. There are no messages using -script, but that doesn't work as I want. Currently on M8.0.1 XP SP3. Will try a different machine tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry - I just missed those errors somehow. I do reproduce them now. No idea why didn't notice them before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the initialization, the kernel code is in a mode which prevents aborts.

Throw/Catch are implemented with Abort, therefore they do not work during initialization.

A simple example that shows the problem is to put this in your test.m file:

```
Catch[Throw[test]];
```

Similarly, functions like TimeConstrained, MemoryConstrained, Break, the Trace family, Abort and those that depend upon it (like certain data paclets) will have problems like this during initialization.

A possible solution to your problem might be to consider the -script option:

```
math.exe -script test.m
```

Also, note that in version 8 there is a documented function called UsingFrontEnd, which does what UseFrontEnd did, but is auto-configured, so this:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
UsingFrontEnd[NotebookWrite[CreateDocument[], "Testing"]];
```

should be all you need in your test.m file.

See also: [Mathematica Scripts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html)

**Addendum**

One possible solution to use the -script and UsingFrontEnd is to use the 'run.m script 
included below. This does require setting up a 'Test' kernel in the kernel configuration options (basically a clone of the 'Local' kernel settings).

The script includes two utility functions, NotebookEvaluatingQ and NotebookPauseForEvaluation, which help the script to wait for the client notebook to finish evaluating before saving it. The upside of this approach is that all the evaluation control code is in the 'run.m' script, so the client notebook does not need to have a NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]] statement at the end.

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},While[NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb],Pause[.25]]]

NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_]:=Module[{},
SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
Or@@Map["Evaluating"/.#&,Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
]

UsingFrontEnd[
nb = NotebookOpen["c:\\users\\arnoudb\\run.nb"];
SetOptions[nb,Evaluator->"Test"];
SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb];
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb];
NotebookSave[nb];
]
```

I hope this is useful in some way to you. It could use a few more improvements like resetting the notebook's kernel to its original and closing the notebook after saving it,
but this code should work for this particular purpose.

On a side note, I tried one other approach, using this:

```
UsingFrontEnd[ NotebookEvaluate[ "c:\\users\\arnoudb\\run.nb", InsertResults->True ] ]
```

But this is kicking the kernel terminal session into a dialog mode, which seems like a bug
to me (I'll check into this and get this reported if this is a valid issue).

Comment: @ Arnoud, Thanks for the explanation.  I am using UseFrontEnd to launch an interactive front end to capture output, as demonstrated in the addendum I have just added. Neither UsingFrontEnd nor MathKernel -script facilitates this, so I plan to carry on using UseFrontEnd albeit with nocatch warning messages.

Comment: @ Arnoud, The `NotebookEvaluatingQ` method is interesting.