# Using code from Mathematica nb. file in VB.Net application

Tags: vb.net, wolfram-mathematica

I have the code in Mathematica nb.file and I want to use it in my VB application via Net/Link.
Is there any way how to use the code from nb.file directly? For example like I will execute the code in Mathematica via VB?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to construct a string with something like the following instructions and send it to the mathkernel Compute function within .NET:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
$FrontEndLaunchCommand = "Mathematica.exe";
UseFrontEnd[nb = NotebookOpen["C:\\Temp\\run.nb"];
  SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
  SelectionEvaluate[nb];];
Pause[10];
CloseFrontEnd[];
```

ref. [Uncaught Throw generated by JLink or UseFrontEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7626491/879601)