# mathematica script run in linux command line

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose we want to integrate e**x in linux command line and every time the integration range may vary.We can call the integration script and input the specified integration range every time in command line.
I have read http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html,but it is sort of terse.
Q1
Is it a .m script necessarily?
Q2
Could it be a nb file?Then the formula could be written easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for something this simple you dont even need a script:

```
echo "Integrate[Exp[x],{x,0,y}]" | math
```

If you want to batch execute notebooks you will need to create a wrapper .m script that opens and evaluates the notebook -- Way overkill for this problem but see here:

[mathematica start front end and eval notebook from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423179/mathematica-start-front-end-and-eval-notebook-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks.echo "Integrate[Exp[x],{x,0,y}]" | math -noprompt  could give a pure result.